# Hazelcast: SqlPredicate facing IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am trying to use SqlPredicate using hazelcast.
Code snippet:

```
private void testHazelCast() {
        HazelcastInstance hazelcast = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
        Employee e1 = new Employee("A", 20, 30);
        Employee e2 = new Employee("C", 25, 45);
        Employee e3 = new Employee("B", 30, 35);
        Employee e4 = new Employee("F", 35, 30);
        Employee e5 = new Employee("E", 40, 40);
        Employee e6 = new Employee(null, 40, 20);
        IMap<Employee, String> map = hazelcast.getMap("employee");
        map.put(e1, "e1");
        map.put(e2, "e2");
        map.put(e3, "e3");
        map.put(e4, "e4");
        map.put(e5, "e5");
        map.put(e6, "e6");

        EntryObject e = new PredicateBuilder().getEntryObject();
        Predicate predicate = new SqlPredicate(String.format("name = A"));
        Set<Employee> employeeSet = map.keySet(predicate);
        System.out.println(employeeSet);
    }

class Employee implements Serializable{
    String name;
    int age;
    int weight;

    public Employee(String name, int age, int weight) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Employee employee = (Employee) o;

        if (age != employee.age) return false;
        if (weight != employee.weight) return false;
        if (!name.equals(employee.name)) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = name.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + age;
        result = 31 * result + weight;
        return result;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

}
```

When I run this, I am getting the following execption:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no suitable accessor for 'name' on class 'class java.lang.String'
>       at com.hazelcast.query.impl.ReflectionHelper.createGetter(ReflectionHelper.java:150)
>       ... 14 more

I need to filter the keys using the SqlPredicate and then retrieve the values using the keys. I have achieved this using PredicateBuilder.

```
Predicate predicate = e.key().get("name").equal("A");
```

I was trying to perform the same activity using the SqlPredicate.
Can anybody please point out where exactly I am doing wrong with SqlPredicate ?

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to apply the predicate on values of the map, so try to use the IMap with String keys and Employee values

Comment: Hi Yugo, Thanks for the inputs. My requirement is such that I need to be able to filter the keys and then get it's values. I have edited my question to be more specific.

Comment: Reading the hazelcast [javadoc][http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html] the keySet method with predicate will evaluate the values and bring you the keys of the entries that match the predicate.

Comment: Thanks for link. I went through the javadoc:
`Set<K> keySet(Predicate predicate)
Queries the map based on the specified predicate and returns the keys of matching entries.`
I may be wrong here but this is what I understood: Based on the predicate, it will fetch the matching keys. So in this case it should have matched a key and returned that.

Comment: The method keySet(Predicate predicate) applies the predicate into the values and returns the respective keys of the matched values. It does not apply the predicate rule into the keys themselves.
So, this method does automatically what you want, but based on a premise your data structure is inverted in the map

Comment: as @yugo pointed out, you probably have a typo here `IMap<Employee, String> map = hazelcast.getMap("employee");`. Correct verion `IMap<String, Emplotee> map = hazelcast.getMap("employee");`. and you need to fix subsequent puts as well

Comment: Thanks Yugo and Vik, I understand this now. However my requirement remains the same as in I have to perform a filter on keys. I did that using PredicateBuilder. so I was just wondering if I could do the same with SqlPredicate.